# Realm migrations in Swift

Tags: swift, migration, realm, data-migration, data-management

I have a Realm Object modeled as so

```
class WorkoutSet: Object {
     // Schema 0
     dynamic var exerciseName: String = ""
     dynamic var reps: Int = 0
     // Schema 0 + 1
     dynamic var setCount: Int = 0
}
```

I am trying to perform a migration.

Within my `AppDelegate` I have imported `RealmSwift`.

Within the function `didFinishLaunchWithOptions` I call

```
Migrations().checkSchema()
```

*Migrations* is a class declared in another file.

Within that file there is a struct declared as so.

```
func checkSchema() {
    Realm.Configuration(
        // Set the new schema version. This must be greater than the previously used
        // version (if you've never set a schema version before, the version is 0).
        schemaVersion: 1,

        // Set the block which will be called automatically when opening a Realm with
        // a schema version lower than the one set above
        migrationBlock: { migration, oldSchemaVersion in
            // We haven’t migrated anything yet, so oldSchemaVersion == 0
            switch oldSchemaVersion {
            case 1:
                break
            default:
                // Nothing to do!
                // Realm will automatically detect new properties and removed properties
                // And will update the schema on disk automatically
                self.zeroToOne(migration)
            }
    })
}

func zeroToOne(migration: Migration) {
    migration.enumerate(WorkoutSet.className()) {
        oldObject, newObject in
        let setCount = 1
        newObject!["setCount"] = setCount
    }
}
```

I am getting an error for adding `setCount` to the model

Comment: What error do you get? Can you share that?

Comment: Property 'setCount' has been added to latest model

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You will need to invoke the migration. Merely creating a configuration, won't invoke it. There are two ways of doing this:

1. Set your configuration with migration as Realm's default configuration-

   ```
   let config = Realm.Configuration(
     // Set the new schema version. This must be greater than the previously used
     // version (if you've never set a schema version before, the version is 0).
     schemaVersion: 1,

     // Set the block which will be called automatically when opening a Realm with
     // a schema version lower than the one set above
     migrationBlock: { migration, oldSchemaVersion in

       if oldSchemaVersion < 1 {
         migration.enumerate(WorkoutSet.className()) { oldObject, newObject in
           newObject?["setCount"] = setCount
         }    
       }
     }
   ) 
   Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = config
   ```

**OR**

2. Migrate manually using migrateRealm :

> migrateRealm(config)

Now your migration should work properly.

Comment: Is there a way to just do this automatically? I think this is pretty straight forward if the value could be nil... any thoughts?

Answer (score 6):

Because you just create `Realm.Configuration`. Migration block is invoked by Realm if needed. You cannot invoke migration directly.

So to be invoke migration block, you should set configuration object to Realm, or set as default configuration. Then create Realm instance.

So You need to do the following:

```
let config = Realm.Configuration(
    // Set the new schema version. This must be greater than the previously used
    // version (if you've never set a schema version before, the version is 0).
    schemaVersion: 1,

    // Set the block which will be called automatically when opening a Realm with
    // a schema version lower than the one set above
    migrationBlock: { migration, oldSchemaVersion in
        // We haven’t migrated anything yet, so oldSchemaVersion == 0
        switch oldSchemaVersion {
        case 1:
            break
        default:
            // Nothing to do!
            // Realm will automatically detect new properties and removed properties
            // And will update the schema on disk automatically
            self.zeroToOne(migration)
        }
})

let realm = try! Realm(configuration: config) // Invoke migration block if needed
```

Comment: dont forget to call import RealmSwift

Comment: Do not call `let realm = try! Realm(configuration: config)` with force. It's marked as throwing for a reason (for example there is no space on device to perform migration). Instead you should call it in a do-catch block.

Answer (score 0):

Update answer @kishikawa katsumi for Xcode 14.3:

```
func zeroToOne(migration: Migration) {
    migration.enumerateObjects(ofType: <Your Realm Object>.className()) { _, newObject in
        newObject![<Your new properties>] = nil
        // Ex: newObject!["release_date"] = nil
    }
}

let config = Realm.Configuration(
    // Set the new schema version. This must be greater than the previously used
    // version (if you've never set a schema version before, the version is 0).
    schemaVersion: 1,

    // Set the block which will be called automatically when opening a Realm with
    // a schema version lower than the one set above
    migrationBlock: { migration, oldSchemaVersion in

        // We haven’t migrated anything yet, so oldSchemaVersion == 0
        switch oldSchemaVersion {
        case 1:
            break
        default:
            // Nothing to do!
            // Realm will automatically detect new properties and removed properties
            // And will update the schema on disk automatically
            zeroToOne(migration: migration)
        }
    }
)

let realm = try! Realm(configuration: config) // Invoke migration block if needed
```

Comment: This doesn't update the referenced answer at all. You've copied that answer's code without any change. It seems you've only changed the original question's `zeroToOne` function.

Comment: Yes. It changed from "enumerate" to "enumerateObjects(ofType:)"